Elementary properties of cohomology
This might be an unusual question, but while reading the section on cohomology in Hatcher's book, I saw that a number of elementary properties of (singular) cohomology can be deduced directly by universal coefficient theorem and the corresponding properties of homology. For example:

Simplicial, cellular and singular cohomology coincide

Since simplicial, cellular and singular homology coincide, so too must the corresponding cohomology theories (by direct application of UCT).

Homotopy invariance

Again, we know that singular homology is homotopically invariant, which means that singular cohomology must be as well (again, direct application of UCT).

Excision

This one follows from the corresponding result for homology, naturality of UCT and five-lemma.
My question is the following: can all axioms for cohomology be deduced in this way? In particular, can we obtain the long exact sequence of cohomology groups for a pair using only the long sequence of homology groups for a pair + UCT? How about Mayer-Vietoris?
I'm not sure if my question is worded well enough, so I'd be glad to clear anything up. Thanks for any response!

How exactly you apply UCT to show homotopy invariance? Or how UCT implies that corresponding cohomologies coincide? I think you use some kind of weak condition here. Both are actually about induced homomorphisms, not just "existence of isomorphism". And I don't really see how UCT implies it.

@freakish I might be misunderstanding this, but doesn't UCT tell us that for singular cohomology, we have $$H^n (X; G) \cong Ext (H_{n - 1} (X), G) \oplus Hom (H_n (X), G)$$ and for cellular cohomology $$H^n {CW} (X; G) \cong Ext ({H{n - 1}}{CW} (X), G) \oplus Hom ({H_n}{CW} (X), G).$$ But we know from homology theory that $H_n (X) \cong {H_n}_{CW} (X)$, so the corresponding summands must be isomorphic?

Yes, but that's not what those properties actually mean. When we say that "cohomologies coincide" we mean the functors are equivalent. Meaning not only groups are isomorphic but also induced homomorphisms are "equal" (naturally equivalent). Similarly homotopy invariance means that homotopic maps induce equal homomorphsisms. This is a lot more than just the fact that homotopy equivalent spaces have isomorphic (co)homology groups.

Ok, I see what you mean. So I basically need to prove that there is a natural transformation between functors $H^n$ and ${H^n}_{CW}$ that map from CW-category into abelian category. Though the analogue statement is obvious for simplicial cohomology, right?

@ronno In this case, the SES are split...
